# How to: Hide video skin when playing, otherwise show skin?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using the default CS4 FLVPlayback skin, mainly the SkinOverPlayMute.swf. I know there's a skinAutoHide option, but because I don't want it to auto play, I want people to see a play button when they first encounter the video (so they don't think it's just an image). But the skin needs to hide when the video is actually playing (so the video doesn't get blocked by the controls).

In other works - when video isn't playing: skin showing; when video is playing: skin hide.

Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, replacing **video_instance** with the instance name of your video obviously.

```
var features:Array = [
    "playButton",
    "pauseButton",
    "playPauseButton",
    "stopButton",
    "muteButton",
    "backButton",
    "forwardButton",
    "volumeBar",
    "seekBar",
    "bufferingBar",
    "fullScreenButton"
];

function setSkinVisible(player:FLVPlayback, bool:Boolean=true):void
{
    var i:String;
    for each(i in features)
    {
        var t:Sprite = player[i];
        if(t != null)
            t.visible = bool;
    }
}

// test
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handle);
function _handle(e:Event):void
{
    setSkinVisible(video_instance, !video_instance.playing);
}
```

Comment: Marty, no luck. When the video starts you can't see the skin, on mouse over you see the pause button on the skin (image:[link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/703/control1o.jpg/)), when i click the pause button the video plays but all control disappears  (image:[link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/703/control1o.jpg/))

Comment: Hm, the easiest way to do this in my honest opinion would be to create your own skin.. Using the inbuilt ones is one of the biggest pains in the behind I know of with AS3.